# Can I link a new Macbook to an old Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-sharing

I just got a Macbook Pro Retina 15". It is sweet.

My old Macbook Pro, which I got in like 2007, can't run anything higher than OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). My new Macbook runs 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).

Is there a relatively simple way to use my old computer with my new one, perhaps as an extra screen?

Comment: You will need a third-party software solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Apple portables doesn't support this kind of behavior as described [on their support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4469). So unfortunately that isn't an option.